# Add custom field to taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am writing a module that creates a vocabulary through code. Here's what I use:

```
$new_vocab_name = 'my_categories';
$vocab_obj = (object) array(
   'name' => t('My Categories'),
   'machine_name' => $new_vocab_name,
);
taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocab_obj);
```

How do I add custom fields for terms that will be in this vocabulary? E.g., I want to add an image field for each term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article will be usefull for You because taxonomy is one of entity types:
[Working programmatically with fields in Drupal 7](http://ado.io/blog/drupal-7/working-programmatically-with-fields-in-drupal-7)

So You should set "entity_types" as taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks; to be more precise, the **entity_type** must be set to **taxonomy_term**, and in order to get a list of available entities, you can use the function **entity_get_info()**.

Comment: I'm also linking to [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36966/how-to-programmatically-set-a-custom-field) because I was having some trouble using the custom field and it helped me sort it out.